# Parametrization of this elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

What's the simplest way to parametrize the curve given by the equation

$$y^2 = (x^2-a^2)^2 - b^2,$$

namely simple functions (polynomials?) $x(z)$, $y(z)$, that would satisfy the above relation. This is (a suitably transformed version of) the equation for a certain elliptic curve which I'm interested in.

Comment: We have $$(x^2-a^2)^2-y^2=b^2\implies\left(\frac{x^2-a^2}b\right)^2-\left(\frac yb\right)^2=1$$ which resembles $$\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=1$$

So, we have $y=b\tan\theta, x^2-a^2=b\sec\theta$ which is not complete

Comment: Parametric solution can be written if all those numbers $x,y,a,b$ -will depend on two parameters. Otherwise it is impossible.